# rspec failure with password_digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial. I am having trouble getting my rspec testing to work. It looks like the encrypted values of the password are not inconsistent, leading to failure. It is puzzling because the results are inconsistent. Sometimes, the tests are passed when I rollback my migration, re-migrate, rake test:prepare, and run the tests again. Sometimes they still fail. Is there a reason for this or have I implemented it incorrectly?

Here is the particular snippet of code of **user_spec.rb**:

```
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before do
        @user.save
    end
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) } #found_user should be the user fetched from the database

    describe "with valid password" do
        it { found_user.authenticate(@user.password).should eq @user }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
        let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("mismatch") }

        it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
        specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
end
```

And sample error message I get:

```
$ rspec spec/
.........F...................
Failures:

1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
 Failure/Error: it { found_user.authenticate(@user.password).should eq @user }

   expected: #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$ZSegpX1GY1RIcqvDmM4FteBQ.HXzHM2pZtj0mwobetfs...">
        got: #<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2014-01-08 09:35:31", updated_at: "2014-01-08 09:35:31", password_digest: "$2a$04$qO1QSOwTEYtioSSmNObKKOgc5K3SQyU4dDk.APqN1egI...">

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -#<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$ZSegpX1GY1RIcqvDmM4FteBQ.HXzHM2pZtj0mwobetfs...">
   +#<User id: 1, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2014-01-08 09:35:31", updated_at: "2014-01-08 09:35:31", password_digest: "$2a$04$qO1QSOwTEYtioSSmNObKKOgc5K3SQyU4dDk.APqN1egI...">

 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:82:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.38035 seconds
29 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:82 # User return value of authenticate method with valid password 

Randomized with seed 23961
```

Once again, sometimes the test passes after rollback, migration, and resetting the test database. Sometimes it still fails. Thanks for your time.

Update - here is how I initialize @user:

```
before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar2", password_confirmation: "foobar2")
end
subject{user}
```

using rake:reset does not seem to fix the problem, the tests still fail sometimes.

Comment: where does the `@user` variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

What `rake db:migrate:status shows?`

I suggest You should Completely remove your DB and then try to migrate. It looks to me that in your DB, the already stored Users passwd are not removed completely,

```
rake db:reset
```

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `subject { @user }` rather than `subject { user }`